Python 3.13 distutils.msvccompiler Not Found Error
During the installation of gymnasium-2048 I came across this rather persistent error message:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named ‘distutils.msvccompiler
A quick google search suggests installing MSVC compiler by Visual Studio Installer, etc. But this alone did not solve the problem. The error message is still the same. Even after restarting and making sure the compiler is installed in its default location (C drive for windows) the error still occurs, suggesting it cannot find a compiler for MSVC somehow.
OS: Windows 10
Python: 3.13.0

If you know the answer, then please post it and accept it as an answer

This is because distuitls is deprecated in python 3.12. So downgrade Python to 3.11 and install the package successfully.
